# Eigenspace decomposition for dual space and $W^{1,1} = W^{1,0} \otimes W^{0,1} \subset \bigwedge^2 W_\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-geometry

I've understood the idea with a real vector spaces $V$ and a complex structure $J$ on $V$ that gives the eigenspace decomposition $V_\mathbb{C} = V^{1,0} \oplus V^{0,1}$.

Now I'm trying to understand the following. If $W=\operatorname{Hom}(V, \mathbb{R})$, then $W_\mathbb{C} := \operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb{C})$ also splits as $$W_\mathbb{C} = W^{1,0} \oplus W^{0,1}.$$

After this $W^{1,1}$ is introduced as $$W^{1,1} = W^{1,0} \otimes W^{0,1} \subset \bigwedge^2 W_\mathbb{C}$$ and furthermore $W_\mathbb{R}:= W^{1,1} \cap \bigwedge^2W _\mathbb{R}$. This is where I fall of the trail.

What are the elements of $W^{1,1}$? Pure tensors like $\varphi \otimes \psi$ where $J(\varphi)=i\varphi$ and $J(\psi')=-i\psi$? And why is $W^{1,1}$ a subspace of $\bigwedge^2 W_\mathbb{C}$, would this not imply that these would be alternating tensors?

This is probably some simple algebra stuff which I don't know, but if anyone can help me with understanding this I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is the definition of $W_\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That is actually missing from the book but I would guess its $\operatorname{Hom}(V, \mathbb{R})$. @wood

Comment: $W^{1,1}$ is the space of $2$-forms which are complex linear in the first argument, and complex anti-linear in the second argument. That is, $\omega\in W^{1,1}\iff \omega(Jv,w)=i\omega(v,w)$ and $\omega(v,Jw)=-i\omega(v,w)$ for all $v,w\in V$ (which, in this case, happens to be equivalent to requiring $J^*\omega=\omega$, but what I said applies to $(p,q)$-forms more generally). Then $W^{1,1}_\mathbb{R}$ consists of those $(1,1)$-forms which are invariant under conjugation.

Comment: @QuaereVerum You should post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ideas here. Probably, two clarifying remarks are:

- $W_\mathbb{C}=V^* \otimes_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{C}$, i.e. it is the complexification of $V$. Note that this is general: given $V,U$ vector spaces, then $Hom(V,U)=V^* \otimes U$.
- Given two vector spaces $U,V$, we have: $\bigwedge^k(V\oplus U)=\bigoplus_\limits{p+q=k}\bigwedge^pV \otimes \bigwedge^qU$. This should provide you with an answer.

Anyway, I just pointed out a couple of ideas but a very clear and not stright answer is given in "Complex Geometry: An Introduction" by D. Huybrechts, section 1.2.

Comment: That's not quite correct. One has $\wedge^k(V\oplus U)=\oplus_{p+q=k}\left(\wedge^pV\otimes\wedge^q U\right)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you it was a typo, I edited it now.